# How can I put a devexpress defaultLookAndFeel Component inside of a devexpress gridcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am trying to put a Devexpress DefaultLookAndFeel Component inside of a devexpress gridcontrol cell. I can't find any references on how to do it. The only examples I see are putting RepositoryItems inside of cells. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by `DefaultLookAndFeel control`. Do you mean that you want to change the look and feel of the grid ?

Comment: There is a control called defaultLookAndFeel that changes the color of all devexpress controls, it's changing the theme color.

Comment: It's not a control, but component (non visual)

Comment: Thanks I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you're doing something wrong because there are no reasons to put the [DefaultLookAndFeel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressLookAndFeelDefaultLookAndFeeltopic) component "inside the XtraGrid". This component is designed to apply the specific [Look And Feel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2397) to the entire application.

If you can change the appearance of grid control rows or individual cells you can use the [Grid's appearances settings](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument755) and/or [Style](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)/[CustomDraw](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument763) events.

Comment: I actually need the control to change the look and feel of the entire app.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the GridControl to have a list of look and feel styles (skins), and change the look and feel of the application when a user clicks on a row?

Comment: @AKADER Please, describe your exact task more detailed because it is not clear how the look and feel of the entire app linked to the specific grid's cell